# How to play mp3 file from internal storage?

Tags: android

simple mp3 player: i want to play a music file from my music folder in the music directory (samsung galaxy s4)

```
private void init()
{
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/calm.mp3"));

    mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mPlayer.start();
}
```

app is crashing when testing on device.

Comment: I think that that 'my music folder' is not contained in that path. Did you check before you called the player? By the way, change the subject of your post as you use external storage.

Comment: sorry, i mean in no folder. just on "phone" in no folder

Comment: Just "on phone" OMG. You should check first if you have the right path. Check if the file exists before calling the mediaplayer.

Comment: I agree with @greenapps. You should check the file path of your mp3 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the file path of your mp3 file. "Just on phone" is not always located in `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/calm.mp3"`.

Another thing I would check is to see if the app has permission to access external storage. In your android manifest, you may need to add External Storage Read Permission. [See Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html).

For example, add the following to the Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```